# Odoo's XML nothing happens whatever i do with the <model>.py file

Tags: python, xml, odoo-9

What i was trying to do the whole time edit the "Tree View" for the Manufacturing Module. I am trying to Add the "product_uom_qty" to the said view in order to see the detail easily. I tried editing the xml but i cant simply just add the column since it's not part of the model but they are related to each other.

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tree decoration-bf="message_needaction==True" decoration-info="state in ('draft','confirmed')" decoration-danger="date_planned&lt;current_date and state not in ('done','cancel')" decoration-muted="state in ('done','cancel')" string="Manufacturing Orders">
                    <field name="message_needaction" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="date_planned"/>
                    <field name="product_id"/>
                    <field name="product_qty" sum="Total Qty"/>
                    <field name="product_uom" options="{'no_open':True,'no_create':True}" groups="product.group_uom"/>
                    <field name="routing_id" groups="mrp.group_mrp_routings"/>
                    <field name="hour_total" sum="Total Hours"/>
                    <field name="cycle_total" sum="Total Cycles"/>
                    <field name="origin"/>
                    <field name="state"/>
                </tree>
```

I tried editing the Python based files which is the mrp.py which contains the columns for the models but unfortunately nothing happened. I even tried to remove all of the codes inside the file but nothing changed after i refresh the pages for the Manufacturing module.

The base model of the codes above is the "mrp.production" which is related to "stock.move" <--contains the product_uom_qty.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a valid xml for odoo where is the tag `<openerp> <data>`   and the tree should be in the `<record>` tag   if you put this file in your model and you didn't get any error you didn"t add it the the `__openerp__.py` in the data: 'your_xml_file.xml'

```
<openerp>
    <data>
           <record id="tree_id" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="model">model.name.here</field>
                <field name="priority" eval="0"/><!-- this tree will be the default tree for the model  -->
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <tree >
                        <field name="field_name"/>
                        <field name="field_name"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

and you should add this file in `__openepr__.py`